# could not connect Mysql sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, setup-deployment, sunspot

I using in my ROR application sunspot gem for search. In my local computer its fine, but after upload on server when want search any I was an eror:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

My sunspot.yml :

```
production:   

solr:    
hostname: localhost    
port:8983    
log_level:WARNING    

development:   solr:   
hostname: localhost    
port: 8982    
log_level:* INFO

test:  
solr:     
hostname: localhost    
port: 8981    
log_level: WARNING
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of hostname :localhost , you will try to give -

hostname: root

password: yourpassword

port: "production port no."

Comment: all fine, was created user on mysql and run db:create (this user), and db:migrate. Thank`s